# Inno Setup - how can I make my program run when a user logs in to Windows?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to use Inno Setup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php) to build an installer for an application.

I want this application to start whenever a user logs in to their account on the Windows machine.

How can I tell Inno Setup to make the program start when a user logs in?

Comment: See also [Option to make application automatically start with Windows when installing using Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40146434/850848).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Put a shortcut in the startup folder of All Users profile. See the knowledge base article '[Create shortcuts in the Startup (or Autostart) group](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?startup)' which includes the below example:

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Icons] 
Name: "{commonstartup}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
```

If you want the program to run only when the user that installed the program logs in, then use [`{userstartup}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#userstartup) instead of [`{commonstartup}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#commonstartup). In that case admin privileges is not required.

Or if you decide to write to 'Run' key of registry ([kb article](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?startwithwindows)):

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "MyProg"; ValueData: """{app}\MyProg.exe"""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

If you use 'HKLM', again admin privileges is required.

Comment: What if I wish to install as a windows service? I tried the way which you have mentioned in your answer. But the program shows up and exits although it has a forever running while loop.

Comment: @rahulserver - You could make a shortcut to "net start svcname".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be helpful for someone...

I encountered some problems under windows 8 when trying to build setup that would automatically put autorun registry key such as:

```
Root: "HKCU"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "NHMMNAS"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

for running my 32-bit .NET application on every Windows startup.
It occured that for 32-bit application a little modification was needed which was replacing `Root: "HKCU"` with `Root: "HKCU32"` so the entry in setup script was:

```
Root: "HKCU32"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "NHMMNAS"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

After adding the line and reinstalling, my application started on system startup with no problems.

Comment: So you were running 64-bit installation mode in which `HKCU` root key maps to 64-bit registry view. It's also worth to mention that you can use task scheduler for this task.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - it hadn't crossed my mind :), but for the task sheduler I think I don't have enough knowledge

Comment: Task scheduler tool is quite well [`described`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx) with many [`examples`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx#BKMK_create), for system startup e.g. [`this one`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx#BKMK_startup).

Comment: Thank you again for your time and for sharing your knowledge. The fine thing is that the tool is accessible from command line and it seems to give some opportunities.