# Inno-Setup: how to let the user choose whether to autostart or not?

Tags: inno-setup, autostart

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490249/inno-setup-how-can-i-make-my-program-run-when-a-user-logs-in-to-windows/7491472) I know how to put an application in the autostart folder without user interaction. But how can I let user decide if he wants that or not via checkbox?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to TLama and some more googling I did it like this:

```
[Tasks]
Name: startup; Description: "Automatically start on login"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"

[Icons]
Name: "{userstartup}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: startup
```

Comment: +1, your solution is definitely better! Working with a scripting part of InnoSetup a lot I'm loosing the contact with the built-in features. Maybe you may accept your post instead ;-)

Comment: Ok, TLama :-) I'll accept it tomorrow (it's still locked). But thanks nevertheless for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome! I'll delete my post from here to not mislead the others with a unnecessarily complicated solution ;-)

Comment: Name: "startup"; Description: "{cm:AutoStartProgram,{#MyAppName}}" to use translated text